# Nested .each on embedded ruby not printing anything

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I'm having some problems with embedded ruby. I'm trying to iterate through some variable, to print some JavaScript code.

This is the following code:

```
<% color1 = '#ff0000' %>
<% color2 = '#00ff00' %>
<% color3 = '#ffff00' %>
<% i = 0 %>
<% j = 0 %>

<% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
      sigInst.addNode('cap<%= chapter.reference %>',{
        label: 'cap <%= chapter.reference %>',
        color: '<%= j%2==0 ? color1 : color2 %>',
        x: <%= i = i %>,
        y: <%= i = i %>
      }).draw();
  <% i = i + 0.1 %>
  <% j=j+1 %>
<% end %>

<% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
  <% chapter.decisions do |decision| %>
        sigInst.addEdge('cap<%= chapter.reference %>_cap<%= decision.destiny_num %>','cap<%= chapter.reference %>','cap<%= decision.destiny_num %>').draw();
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm using Sigma js to implement a graph. The first .each appears in the view, but the second part doesn't print anything. What's happening? Thanks

Comment: What is `chapter.decisions`? Have you debugged and ensured that the attribute `decisions` returns a value?

Comment: should this `y: <%= i = i %>` be `y: <%= j = j %>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to do a `.each` on your decisions.

So the fixed line would be: `<% chapter.decisions.each do |decision| %>`

Ruby has the sometimes annoying feature of allowing you to pass a block to anything, whether it uses it or not. So in this case, you're just passing the block to the decisions method, which does nothing with it.

Comment: "Ruby has the sometimes annoying feature of allowing you to pass a block to anything" should probably be written as "We have this annoying habit of trying to pass a block to things whether they use it or not." I can't blame Ruby for my own mistakes.

Comment: Agreed. There are very valid reasons for why it is that way, was just pointing out that it's a common source of bugs.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that!